# Is there a way to know what sub class is calling the super class?

Tags: java, class

This is a bit of the code i have. Both the Rabbit and Fox classes are sub classes of the super class and they each have a getCounter() method which returns an int. I get an error saying that getCounter() is not a valid method. I know that it doesnt exist in this current class but if the code executes getCounter would be accessible. (getCounter is static too).

```
public static String setGender(Object obj){
    int specificCounter;
    Class s = obj.getClass();
    if(s == Fox.class|| s == Rabbit.class){
        specificCounter = s.getCounter();
```

Comment: You should never use a subclass in the super class!

Comment: So many things wrong here: A) comparing objects using == ... very dangerous. B) using raw types, insted of `Class<?>` or even a more specific type. C) s is type Class. Class does not have a static method getCounter(). That is the thing: you can't call static methods on objects, you call them on `TheActualClass`. ... long story short: the whole approach is all wrong. You should step back, and talk to someone who has more experience, and have that person guide your work.

Comment: If each subclass has a method getCounter() then the super class should have an abstract method getCounter().

Comment: If getCounter is static, you'll need to call the method on the class instead of the instance. Something like `Fox.getCounter` or `Rabbit.getCounter` instead of `s.getCounter`

Comment: And just for the record: an individual fox or rabbit doesnt know how many other foxes and rabbits are out there. *Counting* foxes is a completely different responsibility, and it should NOT go into the fox class itself!

Comment: `if(obj instanceof Fox) specificCounter = Fox.getCounter() else if(obj instanceof Rabbit) specificCounter = Rabbit.getCounter()` seems like the cleanest way to got about it.

Comment: Thank you all.  @ernest_k my code was written that way but i was told to make it simpler. Like if i were to add more animal classes there would be alot of if statements

Comment: @GhostCat: That's a bit harsh... it's perfectly fine to compare Class objects with `==` since they are singletons (within a ClassLoader), and while using raw types is not best practice, it does no harm here.

Comment: @GhostCat i am trying to make sure that a male/female is followed by the opposite gender. So i have a seperate counter for each class.

Comment: I think it's alright @meriton. My teacher tells me the same thing. Thanks tho.

Comment: @meriton He is a newbie struggling with very basic things. Raw types cause issues, using == can quickly cause issues. Thus the best practice for newbies is to know the rules, and follow them. Instead of using an exception that *only* works in very specific cases.

Comment: @IbrahimAbouelseoud I understand that. But that counter doesn't belong INTO the class it is counting!

Answer (score 0):

In object oriented programming languages such as Java, such problems are usually solved using [polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html).

For instance, you could have the base class declare an abstract method, and provide separate implementations in each subclass.

The Java Tutorials I linked to contain an example on how to do this.

Comment: There is still the problem of how to call getCounter of the specific class, even if all animal classes have an interface with the method getCounter(). Say we check if `obj instanceof Animal`, you still can't call `obj.getCounter()` or `Animal.getCounter()`. Without checking instanceof of specific classes i.e. `Fox` like ernest_k mentioned, how would you do it?

Comment: I think OP is better served by a link to a tutorial that teaches the relevant technique, than a specific code sample. ("give a man a fish and feed him for a day, or teach a man to fish, and feed him for a lifetime")

Answer (score 0):

you can use `instanceof` for the class check (`if(obj instanceof Fox)`). But this will lead to many if elses if you have many different sub classes.

But the important thing is that you use polymorphism as mentioned by meriton. From your question I deduce that the provided code is in the super class of Fox and Rabbit, let's assume it's called `Animal`. Now you don't have to receive an Object, but you can receive an Animal. As long as the Animal class has the method `getCounter()` (which can even be overridden by the sub classes for more specific implementations), you can now call `obj.getCounter()`

```
class Animal {
    public static String setGender(Animal obj){
        int specificCounter = obj.getCounter(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As many others have pointed out, there seems to be quite a few problems going on here.

There doesn't seem to be enough information for any one person to help you out. Instead try reading up on how Java works.

java Class- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

java Inheritance- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

java Oracle Documentation & Tutorials-https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by many others, the super class should stand on it's own, and be totally unaware of sub classes.  Sometimes you "have" to do odd things like this, but it should avoided if possible.  In a normal design there are 3 common approaches that would be acceptable:

1. Make "Animal" an interface, all logic would be in the
   implementing classes of the interface
2. Declare Animal abstract, and make setGender abstract, fulling
   implementing the code in the subclasses.
3. Likely best for this scenario: Override the "setGender()" method in
   your subclasses, and perform any specific operations to the subclass
   in there after calling the super.setGender(), if applicable.

Like so:

```
public class Fox extends Animal {
  private String speciesGender;

  @Override
  public void setGender(String gender) {
    super.setGender(gender);

    //add specific stuff for fox
    if(gender.equals("F")) {
      speciesGender = "Vixen";
    } else {
      speciesGender = "Tod"
    }
  }
}
```

The getter for spceciesGender could be abstract in Animal as well forcing the creation of it. Lots of ways to slice it...